# Angular Material Components Not Displayed

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am new to Angular 2 and Angular Material I tried creating one example to check Angular Material but its not working. I am getting empty html page. My code is as follows.

**App Component ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**App Module .ts**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import {MdSidenavModule,MdMenuModule} from '@angular/material';
    import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
    import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MdSidenavModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MdMenuModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


export class AppModule { }
```

**App Component Html;**

```
<!--The whole content below can be removed with the new code.-->


 <link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <div>

 <md-sidenav-container>

   <md-sidenav opened="true">
    <button>
     Add
    </button>
   </md-sidenav>
 </md-sidenav-container>


 <md-menu>
  <button md-menu-item> Settings </button>
  <button md-menu-item> Help </button>
</md-menu>
</div>
```

styles.css

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

**My Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "asyncpipe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

**My angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "asyncpipe"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

I have included all dependencies as per mentioned on web. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Why did you comment out BrowserAnimationsModule? Did you get any issues related to it?

Comment: Yes i was getting following error ERROR in /media/sarang/Data/anguler2/ngmaterial/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts (8,119): Module '"/media/sarang/Data/anguler2/ngmaterial/node_modules/@angular/animations/browser"' has no exported member 'ɵDomAnimationEngine'.

Comment: Also i am getting one warning - WARNING in ../~/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file 'compiler.es5.ts': Error: Can't resolve './compiler.es5.ts' in '/media/sarang/Data/anguler2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular'
 @ ../~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js 11:0-72
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main. Is this causing issue. Or can we ignore warning

Comment: Can you place your `package.json` in the question?

Comment: Sure i will add it in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';` and `MaterialModule` from `imports: []` too. It's deprecated since `beta.3` [[Changelog]](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Also, add `NoopAnimationsModule`

```
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NoopAnimationsModule],
  ...
})
```

I also found your error [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17400) listed in Github. Seems like fallback to `animations` version `4.1.3` is the solution for now.

Try `npm install '@angular/animations"@4.1.3' --save`

Let me know if that helps!

**UPDATE:**

`md-menu` isn't showing up because it needs a `mdMenuTriggerFor` which can open the menu. Until then, it stays hidden. Also, for `sidenav` to work, everything needs to be within the `md-sidenav-container` tag. [Sidenav doc](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview), [Menu doc](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview).

Please change your html code with following:

```
<md-sidenav-container style="height: 500px">

  <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>Menu
  </button>


  <md-sidenav opened="true" #sidenav 
      style="background-color: skyblue">
    <button md-raised-button style="margin: 2px 0 0 6px">
     Add
    </button>
    <p>This is Sidenav</p>
   </md-sidenav>

   <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
     <button md-menu-item (click)="sidenav.open()"> Sidenav </button>
    <button md-menu-item> Settings </button>
    <button md-menu-item> Help </button>
  </md-menu>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5enrfZHqxGaExhEEk3Fh?p=preview)

Comment: Yes Nehal i tried what you told also updated my app.modules.ts file but issue still persist with blank HTML file. Am i missing something in configuration or in code?.

Comment: Write something simple in your Html file like <h1>Hello</h1>, and see if that shows up?

Comment: Yes it shows everything except angular material tags.

Comment: Found the problem. I put your code in a plunker and nothing was showing up. The reason is `md-menu` needs a trigger. So you have to add a `button` which you can click to trigger the menu. Also, if you look in material docs for sidenav, everything needs to be inside `md-sidenav-container`. See my updated answer. Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes Nehal this solved my problem and working correctly now. Thanks for your valuable efforts.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is not especially with your code. From your comments I see that you got problem with one of your project dependencies (`@angular/platform-browser`). There is a bug for that reported in angular:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17400

Try to update your dependencies to the latests one : `4.2.6`

To do that you need to run following command:

```
 npm update
```

To make sure that you are up to date, check version of installed packages:

```
npm ls --depth 0
```

You also don't need to import every component seperately, if you have already imported all via `MaterialModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Looking forward for results :)

Comment: I updated my dependencies error and warning are gone. But still same issue getting blank HTML page. :-(

Comment: @SarangShinde Did you uncomment the lines from your code? Also, since you already imported `MaterialModule`, you don't have to import modules (e.x. `MdMenuModule`) individually **again**.

Comment: @SarangShinde For `md-button`, add `md-button` attribute to `button`.

Comment: There is no error in console Maciej and Yes Edric added md-button and imported MdButtonModule for same. But still issue persist :-(.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I turned out there was no theme in the styles.scss. I added a pre-built theme and the components rendered.